# Is it possible to access Azure App Service Log Files on Windows 10 File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I currently access my WebLog files via Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 which I currently access via FTPS

The ones I am after are, off my App Service website is:

```
Log Files
    Html
       RawLogs
           123345.Log
```

Is it possible to create some form of mapped drive in windows 10 onto this Azure Log folder?

Thanks

EDIT : These logs are not in Azure Storage, but are stored as a WebLog file within the website under "Log Files"

EDIT2 : Struggling to get this work with FTPS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As for I know, there is not a way to map the folder directly on Win 10.

However, you could map the ftp server on win 10 ,maybe this could help you.

Firstly, you need going to Deployment Center and choose FTP way, then get the ftps endpoint, username and password.

Then choose Map network drive on your Windows, and choose "connect to a web site....." like the pic shows.[image]

Click next and choose "Choose a custom network location",next input the ftps endpoint. But in here you need to change **ftps** to **ftp** and click next.
Then follow the steps as you like.

The result folder in your Windows will be `site/wwwroot/`, it doesn't matter, you could click to the root folder then choose LogFiles.

**Update:** change FTPS to FTP ,what you need to do just delete "s".Like `ftps://xxxxx.ftp.p.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot` change it to `ftp://xxxxx.ftp.p.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot`.

Comment: Thank you for this. However I am struggling to get this to work for FTPS. See in Edit2 in question with screenshot

Comment: @SamJolly you could change the FTPS to FTP, just delete the "s". It will work.

Comment: @SamJolly I have updated my answer, you could have a try.